# How to convert object type into float where object can be any type of number like int, long, float, double etc

Tags: c#, casting, numbers

I am having as stream of objects, which can be either type of number like int, short, long, float etc... 
What is the best way to convert it into a number. Best way could be something
`ToNumber(object oNumber)`

```
// Best magic could be
var number = (somemagic) oNumber;

float operator1 = oNumber is int 
  ? (float)(int)oNumber
  : oNumber is long 
     ? (float)(long)oNumber
     : oNumber is float 
        ? (float)oNumber 
        : (float)(int)oNumber;
```

assuming float will be able to take all number expect double

Answer (score 18):

I believe [`Convert.ToSingle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tosingle) will be able to handle any "core" numeric type you throw at it.

Comment: What if my object is float, will I loose precision due to single level precision conversion?

Comment: @user2685250: What do you mean? If it's *already* a `float`, then a conversion to `float` shouldn't lose any precision, no. (There are some subtleties here around intermediate values being handled at higher precision, but fundamentally that won't matter if you want the value with 32-bits of precision...)

Comment: Thanks Jon for confirmation. Essentially I am parsing an postfix expression which can have any number like float, double, int, short, uint, long etc..